# IE 10 & 11 - CSS transition events not firing

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css-transitions, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

I have page transition animation where I slide out the first page and slide in the second page. I'm leveraging the [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event to detect when each transition has complete, rather than use `setTimeout`.

This is working perfectly fine in the latest versions of FireFox and Chrome, however it fails to work in Internet Explorer 10 or 11.

Here's the JavaScript for my working example:

```
const $body = $('body');
let animating = false;
let template = null;

const transitionEvent = () => {
  let el = document.createElement('test');
  let transitions = {
    'transition': 'transitionend',
    'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
    'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
    'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd'
  };

  for (let transition in transitions) {
    if (el.style[transition] !== void 0) {
      return transitions[transition];
    }
  }
}

const endAnimation = ($currentPage, $nextPage) => {
  animating = false;
  resetPage($currentPage, $nextPage);
};

const resetPage = ($currentPage, $nextPage) => {
  $currentPage.remove();
  $nextPage.removeClass().addClass('body-content current-page').removeAttr('style');
  $body.removeClass('lock');
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  console.log('done');
};

const nextUp = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (animating) {
    return false;
  }

  animating = true;
  let $bodyContent = $('.body-content');
  let $node = $('<div class="body-content" />');
  let $page = $(`<div class='page'/>`);
  let transitionEnd = transitionEvent();

  if (template === null) {
    template = $bodyContent.find('.page').html();
  }

  $body.addClass('lock');
  $node.append($page);
  $page.append(template);
  $body.find('script').first().before($node)

  let $currentPage = $('.body-content.current-page');
  let $nextPage = $('.body-content').last();

  $nextPage.css({
    'transform': `translateY(${$currentPage.height()}px)`
  });

  $currentPage.addClass('scale-down').one(transitionEnd, () => {
    $nextPage.addClass('move-from-bottom forefront').css({
      'transform': `translateY(${window.scrollY}px)`
    }).one(transitionEnd, () => {
      endAnimation($currentPage, $nextPage);
    });
  });
};

$(document).on('click', '.next-up', nextUp);
```

The `$nextPage` element's `transitionend` callback is failing to fire, thus preventing the completion of the animation.

I've read that IE has some issues with `transitionend` and certain css properties, in particular flexbox. But I'm not using flexbox and more importantly, the first element's `trasitionend` callback works as intended. Any idea as to what the case might be with my example?

Here's the actual working [example](http://codepen.io/sethkrasnianski/pen/WrWrZo?editors=0010).